# RewriteRule for htaccess note working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get pages that call a variable (from my OLD site) to point to the root level of my blog... using my htaccess file. My knowledge of the htaccess syntax, isn't very good...

For example, any of these pages...

```
www.example.com/blog/?paged=100
www.example.com/blog/?paged=84
www.example.com/blog/?paged=3
```

... will ALL be rewritten as ...
www.example.com/blog/

I tried...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/paged=?$ $1/blog/$2 [R=301,L]
```

... but that only works for paged=1. Any other variable didn't work (i.e. 2, 100). Can someone help with the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to match query string you need to use `RewriteCond` like this.

**If `/blog/.htaccess` doesn't exist:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paged=\d+
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /blog/? [R=302,NC,L]
```

**If `/blog/.htaccess` exists:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^paged=\d+
RewriteRule ^/?$ /blog/? [R=302,NC,L]
```